# Creating a hyperlink to other slides in the same PowerPoint document

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am looking for a way to add a hyperlink to other slides in the same PPTX document, automated using python-pptx. Below was my test, which did not work. Searching online hinted at few solutions using ActionSetting, part, target_slide, rels, rPr.add_ihlinkClick etc, but I couldn't fully understand to bring these together.

Basically, the desired outcome is to create a text that will jump to any other slide by slide number or slide ID (if such thing exists)

```
    p = table.rows[1].cells[1].text_frame.paragraphs[0]
    r = p.add_run()
    r.text = "Testing"
    r.hyperlink.address = "/ppt/slides/rels/slide1.xml"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"?

Comment: Via PowerPoint's object model (and this may not be same in python), you assign a hyperlink's `.SubAddress` property as a comma-delimited string based on `slide.SlideID`, `slide.SlideNumber`, `slide.Name`, `slide.SlideIndex`.

Comment: Thanks. I may consider using COM automation to complement python-pptx for this. The provided answer suggested for XML manipulation directly, which I'm not yet comfortable with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `ActionSetting` bits in `python-pptx` are read-only at the moment. So there's no direct API support for what you're looking for. You'd need to write an extension/workaround function if you want to be able to write these.

There's a pretty solid analysis of the action setting feature space here:
http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/shp-hyperlink.html

If I remember correctly, the only real trick is getting the internal target "URL" for the target slide. I would make an internal link by hand using the PowerPoint UI and examine the XML it produces with `opc-diag`. It might be pretty straightforward to get to something that would work, even if it didn't solve the general case.

Comment: Created using the UI and observed this when looking at the XML file in the slides folder. Doesn't seem to be usable internal link? <a:hlinkClick r:id="rId2" action="ppaction://hlinksldjump"/>

Comment: @idazuwaika This is the hyperlink (click action) element. It links to the *relationship* element via the `r:id="rId2"` attribute. So you have to look in the rels part for the slide and locate the relationship having the matching r:id. The rels file part name is the same as the slide, with '.rels' appended, so like `slide1.xml.rels`. That's where the actual URL is found, in the `Target` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will have to spend some time to go thru PPTX format in more detail. Quite a number of solutions I need depend on this direct XML manipulation.

Comment: hey @scanny don't want to open up a new question for something arbitrary - but can you remove a hyperlink from a pptx? I need to do the same edit to a boiler plate pptx from PowerBI that requires me to resize images and remove hyperlinks - i need to do this for 40+ pages and I'm having trouble editing this with the XML only the .xml.rels throws me

Comment: It's really a separate question @Datanovice. If you create a new question and mark it with the `python-pptx` tag I'll have a look.

Comment: @scanny you are totally correct : I've asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846721/removing-hyperlinks-and-resizing-images-same-per-every-page-in-powerpoint-by-e

Answer (score 0):

You could also "cheat" by using the shape.click_action (as shape you could simply use the shape containing the textbox):

```
    def create_hyperlink(run, shape, to_slide):
        shape.click_action.target_slide = to_slide
        run.hyperlink.address = shape.click_action.hyperlink.address
        run.hyperlink._hlinkClick.action = shape.click_action.hyperlink._hlink.action
        run.hyperlink._hlinkClick.rId = shape.click_action.hyperlink._hlink.rId
        shape.click_action.target_slide = None
```

Thats how its done in python-pptx-interface (because I wasn't able to get the correct rId otherwise ^^). Have a look at [PPTXCreator.add_content_slide](https://github.com/natter1/python_pptx_interface/blob/f79ec57fa530c6e6c38a37c6452df86a43155e6d/pptx_tools/creator.py#L281).