# Removing hyperlinks in PowerPoint with python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Quite new to XML and the python-pptx module I want to remove a single hyperlink that is present on every page

my own attempt so far has been to retrieve my files, change to `zip` format and unzip them into separate folders

I then locate the following attribute `<a:hlinkClick r:id="RelId4">`

and remove it whilst removing the `Relationship`attribute within the `xml.rels` file which corresponds to this slide.

I then rezip and change the extension to pptx and this loads fines. I then tried to replicate this in Python so I can create an on-going automation.

my attempt:

```
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile as zf
from pptx import Presentation
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = 'mypath'
ppts = [files for files in Path(path).glob('*.pptx')]
for file in ppts:
    file.rename(file.with_suffix('.zip'))
zip_files = ppts = [files for files in Path(path).glob('*.zip')]

for zips in zip_files:
    with zf.ZipFile(zips,'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(Path(path).joinpath('zipFiles',zips.stem))
```

I then do some further filtering and end up with my xmls from the rels folder & the ppt/slide folder.

it's here that I get stuck I can read my xml with the `ElementTree` Module but I cannot find the relevant tag to remove?

```
for file in normal_xmls:
    tree = (ET.parse(file).getroot())
    y = tree.findall('a')
    print(y)
```

this yields nothing, I tried to use the python-pptx module but the `.Action.Hyperlink` doesn't seem to be a complete feature unless I am misunderstanding the API.

Comment: This is really two questions @datanovice. SO is really set up for single-question/single-answer format and that makes it much more likely for folks to find what they're looking for on search. If you break this into two separate questions I'll take a look at both of them.

Comment: @scanny just about to hit the gym but I'll edit a soon as I'm back thanks will mention you when I have if that's cool

Comment: @scanny edited into a single question, let me know if you need to see the XML of the pptx.

Comment: Please describe the hyperlink that is on multiple slides. Is it a hyperlinked shape or is it within text? Can you identify the shape it resides in?

Comment: @scanny if image comes under shape, then yes it's within a shape. There is no text anywhere within the pptx so can only be a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a hyperlink from a shape (the kind where clicking on the shape navigates somewhere), set the hyperlink address to `None`:

```
shape.click_action.hyperlink.address = None
```

Comment: friggin hell, that was simple, guess I have a long way to go with reading documentation thanks for the answer & for providing such a great open source package. I'll be using this for a large company in the UK once we are live i'll send you an email regarding the project if you like.

Comment: I'd love to hear about it @Datanovice, best of luck going forward :)